# Live capable highspeed camera for Linux?

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, v4l

I am tasked to set up a number of highspeed cameras on top of a foosball *(? aka. table soccer ?)* table to allow for slowmotion replay of interesting moves and goals.
So far a test setup is ok by all electrical means, we have sensors in the goalkeeper's foot to detect holding of the ball, laser-light photoelectric barriers to detect a goal and a manual, wireless switch for a referee to tell the system something interesting just happened (and, thus, trigger a manual slowmotion replay) using plain old webcams.
And yes, I'm planning on releasing the whole system as open source plans ;)

Now, does anyone know of a good highspeed camera system (>= 720p @ >=120 fps) that's either connected via USB or LAN/WiFi that works well under Linux with (hopefully) ffmpeg or V4L?